# Freemarker if-else in list (scope)

Tags: templates, freemarker, template-engine

In a list I want to incorporate a if host.machine == 1 then action=Set else action=Create

I want the following output
`Type:Machine;Action:Set;Attributes[Name:machine1~NodeManager.ListenAddress:10.104.17.70~NodeManager.ListenPort:5558]<BR>
    Type:Machine;Action:Create;Attributes[Name:machine2~NodeManager.ListenAddress:10.104.17.71~NodeManager.ListenPort:5558]<BR>`

My data

`hosts:[{"name": "trfuoemlpa004v", "node": 0, "server": 1, "Machine": 1, "ManagedPort": "7002", "SSLPort": 1081},
       {"name": "trfuoemlpa007v", "node": 1, "server": 2, "Machine": 2, "ManagedPort": "7002", "SSLPort": 1081}]`

I have made different templates all fails:

1)
`<#list hosts as host><#assign machine=${host.machine}><#if machine == 1><#assign action="Set"><#else><#assign action="Create"></#if>Type:Machine;Action:${action};Attributes[Name:${host.machine}~NodeManager.ListenAddress:${host.name}~NodeManager.ListenPort:${nodeManagerPort}]<BR></#list>`

`**freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "}" at line 8, column 40 in
J2EE.properties.
Was expecting one of:">" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    "?" ...
    "!" ...
    <TERMINATING_EXCLAM> ...
    "??" ...
    "+" ...**`

2)
`<#list hosts as host><#if host.machine == 1><#assign action="Set"><#else><#assign action="Create"></#if>Type:Machine;Action:${action};Attributes[Name:${host.machine}~NodeManager.ListenAddress:${host.name}~NodeManager.ListenPort:${nodeManagerPort}]<BR></#list>`

`**freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression host.machine is undefined**`

3)
`<#list hosts as host><#if $host.machine} == 1 > ...`

`**freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "}" at line 8, column 40 in
J2EE.properties.
Was expecting one of:">" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    "?" ...
    "!" ...
    <TERMINATING_EXCLAM> ...
    "??" ...
    "+" ...**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd one is the correct one, because `$` has no special meaning *inside* FreeMarker expressions (except inside string literals). `${expression}` is only used to insert the value of an expression into the *static text* (or into a string literal). The error message means that the `host` variable has no sub-variable called `machine` or it's `null`. In the last case, you had to specify some default for it, like `host.machine!0`.

BTW, this:

`<#if host.machine == 1><#assign action="Set"><#else><#assign action="Create"></#if>Type:Machine;Action:${action};`

can be written like this:

`Type:Machine;Action:<#if host.machine == 1>Set<#else>Create</#if>;`

Comment: Right. It was because it was wrong case (machine/Machine).

Type:Machine;Action:<#if host.Machine == 1>Set<#else>Create</#if>;